# OkHttp Request is not public in com.squareup.okhttp; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: compiler-errors, okhttp

I'm trying to get OkHttp to work in my Android Studio project, I created a class and pasted in the following code from here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/recipes/ParseResponseWithGson.java

```
package com.my.project;

/**
 * Created by me on 07/08/2015.
 */
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public final class ParseResponseWithGson {
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
private final Gson gson = new Gson();

public void run() throws Exception {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.github.com/gists/c2a7c39532239ff261be")
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

    Gist gist = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(), Gist.class);
    for (Map.Entry<String, GistFile> entry : gist.files.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue().content);
    }
}

static class Gist {
    Map<String, GistFile> files;
}

static class GistFile {
    String content;
}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    new ParseResponseWithGson().run();
}
}
```

Here's my gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'prebuilt-libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.project_02"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.2"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile files('libs/GlassVoice-xe22.jar')

}
```

but the errors "Error:(8, 27) error: Request is not public in com.squareup.okhttp; cannot be accessed from outside package" and "Error:(9, 27) error: Response is not public in com.squareup.okhttp; cannot be accessed from outside package" occur in the ParseResponseWithGson class for the code:

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix these errors? It seems like the constructor isn't public but that sounds strange however I've copied and pasted the code so I'm not sure what I could have done wrong, unless the wrong version of OkHttp and OkIo are somehow being referenced?

Comment: It seems like the constructor for Request (https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Request.java) and Response are private, which would explain why the error is happening however I don't understand why the example code hasn't been updated if this is a problem with the example, especially considering it seems like a popular library, so I'm assuming I haven't implemented this correctly but have no idea what is missing/hasn't been implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the line `compile files('libs/GlassVoice-xe22.jar')` was causing the issue, I guess it contains an obsolete version of OkHttp because once I removed that line the code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another, obsolete, version of OkHttp on your classpath. That old version’s Request wasn't public, but the one in 2.0+ is.

Try using `jar tvf libs/foo.jar` for each jar in your libs directory to find it!

Comment: FYI, posted answer. I didn't know how to use `jar tvf libs/foo.jar` for each jar in the libs directory. I understood you meant foo.jar should be replaced with the jar name and I assumed the aforementioned command should be written in the Terminal and the current directory of the terminal should be the libs directory but didn't know what kind of output should be expected. When I tried to figure it out, an error " 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command" was returned. Just writing this feedback in case it may be of help to anyone.
Your comment pointed me in the right direction